# changed name servers, but AWS still blocking site

Tags: amazon-web-services, nameserver, cname-record, soa-record

I was advised that changing name servers over to a traditional hosting service would be enough to move the site, but it's not working and I think amazon is still controlling something. Is it possible that I need to change more than the name servers?

The A records are pointing to a CloudFront distribution that I have disabled.

The SOA is amazon, not sure what it is.

Two C name records are amazon.

Is something stopping the new nameservers from working?

I have posted an image of the Route 53 records for reference

[image: Route 53 records]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the delegation has not been updated (through your registrar).

The delegation still looks like this:

```
rawgymsdublin.com.      172800 IN NS ns-474.awsdns-59.com.
rawgymsdublin.com.      172800 IN NS ns-899.awsdns-48.net.
rawgymsdublin.com.      172800 IN NS ns-1586.awsdns-06.co.uk.
rawgymsdublin.com.      172800 IN NS ns-1276.awsdns-31.org.
```

This is crucial to change in order to change nameservers, and should not be confused with NS records in your own zone (however, those are expected to match).